# How to setup supertokens-auth-react with createBrowserRouter from react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Supertokens has pretty good explanation how to setup routing using BrowserRouter, but I would like to use it with createBrowserRouter

Right now it looks like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import SuperTokens, { SuperTokensWrapper, getSuperTokensRoutesForReactRouterDom } from "supertokens-auth-react";
import * as reactRouterDom from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SuperTokensWrapper>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        {/*This renders the login UI on the /auth route*/}
                        {getSuperTokensRoutesForReactRouterDom(reactRouterDom)}
                        {/*Your app routes*/}
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </SuperTokensWrapper>
        );
    }
}
```

but I need this one

```
import SuperTokens, { getSuperTokensRoutesForReactRouterDom } from 'supertokens-auth-react';
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as reactRouterDom from 'react-router-dom';
import Error from '../pages/Error';
import Root from '../pages/Root';
import { supertokensConfig } from '../supertokensConfig';

SuperTokens.init(supertokensConfig);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  getSuperTokensRoutesForReactRouterDom(), // ????
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

A few hours later I came across a [discussion of the issue in *supertokens-auth-react*'s repository](https://github.com/supertokens/supertokens-auth-react/issues/581#issuecomment-1246998493), where I found example how to handle my question

For those of you who don't want to open a discussion, just add this to your code:

```
import SuperTokens, { getSuperTokensRoutesForReactRouterDom } from 'supertokens-auth-react';
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as reactRouterDom from 'react-router-dom';
import { supertokensConfig } from '../supertokensConfig';

SuperTokens.init(supertokensConfig);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  ...getSuperTokensRoutesForReactRouterDom(reactRouterDom).map((r) => r.props),
  // Your app routes
]);
```